# Want to convert a 32 bit IEEE String to decimal in Java.

Tags: java, decimal, ieee

I'm trying to convert a 32 digit String to a decimal...

Example: 
"00111111100000000000000000000000"  >  1
and 
"01000001101000000000000000000000"  > 20

I'm trying the below code but the result I'm getting is totally wrong. 
"00111111100000000000000000000000"  > 2147483647

```
    String s = "00111111100000000000000000000000"
    float fl = Float.parseFloat(s);
    int bits = Math.round(Math.abs(fl));
    decTextView.setText(Long.toString(bits));
```

Any advise?

Comment: why are you going from float -> int -> long???? pick one

Comment: is it a float value or integer/long value? Also your examples are not clear

Comment: I want to convert a 32 digit string representing a IEEE 32 bit floating point to decimal.
How should I change the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do three things.

- Read the 0s and 1s in the String as an `int`.
- Use `intBitsToFloat` to convert the `int` to a `float`.
- Convert the `float` to a decimal (`BigDecimal`).

.

```
int bits = Integer.parseInt(s,2);
float value = Float.intBitsToFloat(bits);
BigDecimal asDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

32 bits number as String can be parsed into an integer when doing

```
String s = "00111111100000000000000000000000";
int myInt= Integer.parseInt(s, 2);
```

trying to parse the same string as float will break the conversion since floats

are defined as **sign + exponent + mantissa** which is a totally different representation than a 2 complement signed int

Comment: No, OP has said in a comment that the binary string is the `float` representation, not the `int` representation of his number.  This doesn't do what he asked for.